# Bootstrap 4 list item single line only (ellipsis not working)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a Bootstrap 4 card, with list items. I want each list text to be only single line, and take up to full width of the card, otherwise show 3 dots (ellipsis) or simply hide it with `overflow:hidden`, but it's not working.

This is the problem:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="card">
  <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
    <li class="list-group-item"><p>Long content ............. Here. Overflow Ellipsis or Hidden not working (This should be 1 line of card width, on all screen sizes, and depending on screen size)</p></li>
    <li class="list-group-item"><p>Second List Item</p></li>
    <li class="list-group-item"><p>Third List Item</p></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Downvoters? I don't see a problem with this first question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use the Bootstrap 4 `text-truncate` class..

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="card">
  <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
    <li class="list-group-item"><p class="text-truncate">Long content ............. Here. Overflow Ellipsis or Hidden not working (This should be 1 line of card width, on all screen sizes, and depending on screen size)</p></li>
    <li class="list-group-item"><p>Second List Item</p></li>
    <li class="list-group-item"><p>Third List Item</p></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[Codeply demo](https://www.codeply.com/go/ILmodF8on2)

Read more about [Bootstrap 4 text utilities](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/text/#text-wrapping-and-overflow)

Comment: Thank you, that's it! May I ask another question related? What would be the best option to add a "down arrow" near the 3-dots to show the user he can expand the list item (I have a script that expands the list to show the full content if it's too long) But my arrow messes up the design (Adding <i class="material-icons">expand_more</i> of material design won't work because it's truncated)

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure. It sounds like a separate question/issue.

Comment: `text-nowrap` is my choice

Answer (score 1):

Use the following styles on p tag inside the li tag

```
white-space: nowrap;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
overflow: hidden;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```css
p {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="card">
  <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
    <li class="list-group-item"><p>Long content ............. Here. Overflow Ellipsis or Hidden not working (This should be 1 line of card width, on all screen sizes, and depending on screen size)</p></li>
    <li class="list-group-item"><p>Second List Item</p></li>
    <li class="list-group-item"><p>Third List Item</p></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```